# Error starting Postgres

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04

I've got a strange error on a live site (as well as it's corresponding dev site) where the Postgres database does not want to start. This issue has occured suddenly, and I don't know what could have caused it.

Attempting to start in terminal gives the dreaded 'not accepting 5432 connections'

```
sudo -u postgres psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

If I try restarting postgres:

```
service postgresql restart
 * Restarting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server                                                                                                                                                                    * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2015-07-15 13:49:24 EEST LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2015-07-12 20:02:18 EEST
2015-07-15 13:49:24 EEST FATAL:  could not open file "/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem": Permission denied
2015-07-15 13:49:24 EEST LOG:  startup process (PID 11172) exited with exit code 1
2015-07-15 13:49:24 EEST LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
```

Any ideas on what to try next, or what could have caused this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was related to an [fsync permissions bug in an update](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/May_2015_Fsync_Permissions_Bug), which was triggered when our VPS provider needed to reboot following another issue.

The steps listed in the article fixed the problem:

```
(as root)
# go to PGDATA directory
cd /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main

# Backup server.crt server.key just to be sure!
cp server.crt server.crt.bk
cp server.key server.key.bk

ls -l server.crt server.key

# confirm both of those files are symbolic links
# to files in /etc/ssl before going further

# remove symlinks to SSL certs
rm server.crt
rm server.key 

# copy the SSL certs to the local directory
cp /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem server.crt
cp /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key server.key

# set permissions on ssl certs
# and postgres ownership on everything else
# just in case
chown postgres *
chmod 640 server.crt server.key

service postgresql start
```

Comment: Thanks @iharob - can only do this after 2 days!

Comment: My  /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main does not have server.crt and server.key. In fact they are not to be found anywhere on my whole hard drive (

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh is you still have the issue you can re-generate the certs using the following command `make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil --force-overwrite` Had the same issue and this solved it.

Answer (score 5):

make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil --force-overwrite

When I'd rewrited certificates I started to have access to postgresql.
And after all - reason why was very simple (when you reload server Ubuntu 18.04. in my case) you're losing some default settings. Be careful.
Thanks a lot of @AndrewSavinykh for help. Дякую теска))).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, some ubuntu/postgres upgrade changed the permissions of the file to 600.

Changing it to 644 solved the problem and I could start the postgre daemon.

chmod 644 /etc/ssl/certs7ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem